# Как сделать таймер стилизованный?

Tags: javascript

Надо сделать собственный таймер, только не пойму как его реализовать. То есть для меня не понятно как цифры разделить на 2 части 00, то есть получить 0 0. Или как-то не правильная реализация?

```js
window.onload = function(){
  function timer(){
    let minute = document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML;
    let second = document.getElementById('second').innerHTML;
    let end = false;

    if(second > 0) second--;
    else {
      second = 60;
      if( minute > 0) minute--;
      else {
        end = true;
      }
    }
    if(end){
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      alert('Время истекло');
    } else {
      document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML = minute;
      document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = second;
    }
  }
  window.intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
```

```css
#timer{
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#timer div{
  display: inline;
}
#timer #operator{
  float: left;
  font-size: 31px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#timer div div{
  float: left;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: 'GOST type B Standard Bold', 'GOST type B Standard', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #7c7768;
  width: 24px;
  height: 29px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background: #2a2422;
  color: #7c7768; 
}
```

```html
<div id='timer'>
  <div id='minute'>
    <div><span>1</span></div>
    <div><span>5</span></div>  
  </div>
  <div id='operator'>:</div>
  <div id='second'>
    <div><span>0</span></div>
    <div><span>0</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но может как-то по другому надо его реализовывать, просто не пойму чтобы цифры менялись и этимх блоках по одной цифре

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну тут может быть миллион идей, вот можно например так в лоб разбить значения.

```js
function timer() {
  let minute = document.getElementById('m').innerHTML + document.getElementById('mm').innerHTML;
  let second = document.getElementById('s').innerHTML + document.getElementById('ss').innerHTML;
  let end = false;

  if (second > 0) second--;
  else {
    second = 59;
    if (minute > 0) minute--;
    else {
      end = true;
    }
  }
  if (end) {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    alert('Время истекло');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('m').innerHTML = Math.floor(minute / 10);
    document.getElementById('mm').innerHTML = minute % 10
    document.getElementById('s').innerHTML = Math.floor(second / 10);
    document.getElementById('ss').innerHTML = second % 10;
  }
}
window.intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

```css
#timer {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#timer div {
  display: inline;
}

#timer #operator {
  float: left;
  font-size: 31px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#timer div div {
  float: left;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: 'GOST type B Standard Bold', 'GOST type B Standard', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #7c7768;
  width: 24px;
  height: 29px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background: #2a2422;
  color: #7c7768;
}
```

```html
<div id='timer'>
  <div id='minute'>
    <div><span id='m'>1</span></div>
    <div><span id='mm'>5</span></div>
  </div>
  <div id='operator'>:</div>
  <div id='second'>
    <div><span id='s'>0</span></div>
    <div><span id='ss'>0</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Такой вопрос, а что означает document.getElementById('mm').innerHTML = minute % 10

Comment: остаток от целочисленного деления значения `minute` на `10`

Comment: То есть это 10% от этой суммы, но допустим 15 это будет 1.5. Он же если это целое число 1 Или я неправильно рассуждаю?

Comment: Не процент, а остаток от деления. `15 % 10 == 5`

Comment: А все понял Понял